# Capitalize everything in a list

Tags: scala, list, capitalize

I know that _.capitalize will capitalize a string but I have a list of strings that needs to be capitalized Ex.

```
val FUND: List[String] = List("f", "aH1", "h","D")
Fund.capitalize
```

I need to change everything to upper case in this code that isn't already, however this gives me an error line under it.

What I would like the list to look like it ("F","AH1","H","D")

What is the best way to accomplish this task.

Comment: what's wrong with FUND.map(_.toUpperCase)

Comment: `"foobar".capitalize == "Foobar" && "foobar".toUpperCase == "FOOBAR"`. You asked for a way to capitalize the strings, but accepted an answer that converted them to upper case. Which one did you want now?

Comment: @RamanMishra It does not capitalize the strings, that's wrong. The method `capitalize` capitalizes the strings.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin yes thanks for pointing out I thought he wants the upper case because there was no example

Comment: My apologies for the confusion I will ensure all my questions from here on out are much more detailed. Thank you for the suggestions of using .toUpperCase that is actually what I need to do.

Comment: Though I am curious how would you capitalize all strings in an list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`capitalize` is not a function on `List` which is why you are seeing an error. As @Raman suggests you can apply the function `toUpperCase` to each element in the List with the function `map`.

i.e.

```
scala> val FUND: List[String] = List("f", "aH1", "h","D")
FUND: List[String] = List(f, aH1, h, D)

scala> FUND.map(xs => xs.toUpperCase)
res0: List[String] = List(F, AH1, H, D)
```

Comment: Why are you all using `toUpperCase` everywhere? The OP clearly attempted to use `capitalize`, not `toUpperCase`.